# 2-Tier SQL Server database example in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I'm currently working on a project that requires connection to a SQL Server 2008 database over a LAN network. I intend using one computer as a server where the database will be on, while the others will connect to the server. I've done a thorough search but couldn't find any material on this. All the examples and materials I've seen seem to skip the topic of database connection over a LAN. Does anyone know how I can do this? I would like to see a simple code showing how this is done (in VB.net since that's the language that I'm using).

Comment: What do you mean by "skip database connection over a LAN"?

Comment: Unclear.... most samples I see deal with exactly this - your client app defines a connection string to a server, which is reached over the LAN - so what exactly are you looking for??

Comment: @marc_s. Where did you see the Example? (note that I'm talking of code in VB.net)

Comment: will it always be over a LAN or will you ever want this to work outside of the office?

Comment: @David. it will always be over the lan

Comment: Can you please mark this as an answer or let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connecting to SQL Server over the network is no different to connecting to SQL Server on your local machine. Simply...

```
Using Conn As New SqlConnection(connstring)
   //Do something here
End Using
```

For information about your connection string have a look at  [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008)

There are a few gotchas though that have more to do with networking and firewalls than any code you will have to write so before you start make sure you can connect to your server with SQL Server Management Studio or similar.  Make sure you SQL Server is configured to allow incoming connections.

Depending on the nature of your application and the number of users this may not be the best archictecture.  Make sure you are using windows authentication as you really don't want to be storing SQL Connection Strings with username and passwords in config files on the client machines.